# Как использовать переменную за пределами async function?

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста есть такой код

```
const urlChannel = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=' + channelID + '&fields=items%2Fsnippet%2Fthumbnails&key=' + apiKey;

async function getChannel(){
      const urlChannelResult = await fetch(urlChannel)
      const jsonChannel = await urlChannelResult.json()
      const authorPhoto = jsonChannel.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.high.url;
      console.log(authorPhoto)
    }
    getChannel()
```

Как можно использовать константу authorPhoto за пределами функции?
p.S Код что выше - находится внутри цикла map, поэтому channelID каждый раз меняется..

Comment: Прежде всего, нехудо бы, чтобы функция возвращала эту переменную через return. А потом уже рыть в сторону промисов или обратных вызовов.

Comment: Каллбеки и промисы наше всё